# Dynamically setting column width in itext java

Tags: java, itext

I have a html table which is being exported to pdf using itext library. In some cases long words in a cell is split into 2 word like "Example123" to "Exampl" and "e123". How to remedy this?
Thank you

Comment: If the cell isn't wide enough for a word to fit, it will be split. In your case, it is split in a very unfortunate way. Introducing hyphenation would split it in a more acceptable way (but split it anyway). The behavior you describe tells me that you aren't using the most recent version of iText. We fixed the problem you describe in the [pdfHTML add-on](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML) of [iText 7](http://itextpdf.com/itext7).

Comment: Yeah, the most recent version of itext is not being used in the project. Thanks for clearing that up.